# How to compare each element of two different databases in text files using perl?

Tags: list, loops, perl, compare

I am trying to compare each element of column 1 from one list (**screens.txt**) with any element of column 1 from the other list (**new_list.txt**) and if matched, print the whole row of the list (**screens.txt**) in a separate text file (**matched.txt**). 
I managed to select the right columns but the output I am getting are the rows from the list (**new_list.txt**) instead of list (**screens.txt**) and only one hit was found so it looks like there is also a problem with a loop.

**new_list.txt** format => first_column->double_tab->the_rest

I am very new in perl programming. Any help would be very much appreciated!

Here is what I've go so far:

```
#!usr/bin/perl

use warnings;

$list = "new_list.txt";
$screens = "screens.txt";
$result = "matched.txt";

open (FA, "<$list") or die "Can't read source file $list: $!\n";
open (RES, ">$result") or die "Can't write on file $result: $!\n";

$n = 0;
$column = 10;
while ($line = <FA>) {
    @description = split (' ', $line);
    @ID = split ('\\t', $description[0]);   
       #print just first column from the list
      #  print "$ID[0]\n";
}

close (FA);

open (FA, "$screens") or die "Can't read source file $screens: $!\n";

while ($file = <FA>) {
    @table = split (' ', $file);
    @accession_no = split ('\ ', $table[0]);
      # print the first column from the list    
      #  print "$accession_no[0]\n";
}

open (FA, "<$list") or die "Can't read source file $list: $!\n";

while ($line = <FA>) {
    print "$line\n";
    @description = split (' ', $line);
    @ID = split ('\\t', $description[0]);
    if ($accession_no eq $ID[0]) {
        $n = $n+1;
        for ($i = 0; $i < $column; $i++) {
            print RES "$file";
        }

        print "\n";
    }   
}

close (FA);
close (RES);

print "Hits found: $n\n";
```

Here is a sample of next_list.txt:
                                                                     Q9UKA8     RCAN3_HUMAN  0

Q9UKA8-2        RCAN3_HUMAN  0

Q9UKA8-3        RCAN3_HUMAN  0

Q9UKA8-4        RCAN3_HUMAN  0

Q9UKA8-5        RCAN3_HUMAN  0

Q9GZP0      PDGFD_HUMAN  0

here is the input file from screens.txt:

Q9GZP0  GDLDLASEST  Scaffold attachment factor B2 (SAF-B2)  SAFB2

Q9UKA8-5 QKAFNSSSFN Ran GTPase-activating protein 1 (RanGAP1)   RANGAP1

I'm interested in checking if **Q9GZP0** and **Q9UKA8-5** (first column)

from **screens.txt** are in first column of **new_list.txt** and if they

are then print the whole line/row from **screens.txt**.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you include a sample of the input files?

Comment: Please update the question instead of posting a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this helps you:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $file1 = "file_pr1.txt";
my $file2 = "file_pr2.txt";
my $resulted_list = "result_list.txt";

my (@description, @ID, @data);

open (my $FA, "<$file1") or die "Can't read source file $file1: $!\n";

while (my $line = <$FA>) {
    chomp($line);
    @description = split (/\s+/, $line);
    push (@ID, $description[0]);   
}
close($FA);

my %params = map { $_ => 1 } @ID; #add each elements into hash

open (my $RES, ">$resulted_list") or die "Open as write error : $!\n";

open (my $FB, "<$file2") or die "Can't read source file $file2: $!\n";

while (my $line = <$FB>) {
    chomp($line);
    @data = split (/\s+/, $line);
    print $RES $line."\n" if(exists($params{$data[0]})); #Write to result file
}
close($RES);
```

Answer (score 1):

Minimal code to filter **screens** with power of `map` block

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $input1 = 'new_list.txt';
my $input2 = 'screens.txt';

my %seen;

open my $fh1, "< $input1"
    or die "Couldn't open $input1";

map{ $seen{$1} = $2 if /(\S+)\s(.*)/ } <$fh1>;

close $fh1;

open my $fh2, "< $input2"
    or die "Couldn't open $input2";

map{ print if /(\S+)\s+(.*)/ and $seen{$1} } <$fh2>;

close $fh2;
```

Input: new_list.txt

```
Q9UKA8 RCAN3_HUMAN 0
Q9UKA8-2 RCAN3_HUMAN 0
Q9UKA8-3 RCAN3_HUMAN 0
Q9UKA8-4 RCAN3_HUMAN 0
Q9UKA8-5 RCAN3_HUMAN 0
Q9GZP0 PDGFD_HUMAN 0
```

Input: screens.txt

```
Q9GZP0 GDLDLASEST Scaffold attachment factor B2 (SAF-B2) SAFB2
Q9UKA8-5 QKAFNSSSFN Ran GTPase-activating protein 1 (RanGAP1) RANGAP1
```

Output:

```
Q9GZP0 GDLDLASEST Scaffold attachment factor B2 (SAF-B2) SAFB2
Q9UKA8-5 QKAFNSSSFN Ran GTPase-activating protein 1 (RanGAP1) RANGAP1
```

NOTE:

Linux -- Make the program executable with a command `chmod og+x program.pl`

Windows -- Run the program as `perl program.pl`

REDIRECT output into a file with a command:

Linux - `program.pl > matched.txt`

Windows - `perl program.pl > matched.txt`